# Error Parsing and Validating User Input

Tags: java

I'm writing some code where the user inputs a length, and it displays what they have entered. I'm just wondering how I could add an error thing onto it so that if they don't enter a number they are told to 'Please enter a number' and then they can retry?

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the length in centimeters : ");
    length1 = in.nextDouble();       
    System.out.println("You entered : " + length1);
```

Comment: Try to add a loop like `while(user_has_entered != true`! And then in the loop check if user has entered something valid set `user_has_entered` to true (or `break` the loop), otherwise send error!

Comment: look up try{}catch{} blocks.

Comment: Also, change your question title to a meaningful one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will check to make sure that the user gave a number as input:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double length1;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Please enter the length in centimeters : ");
        String s = in.next();
        try {
            length1 = Double.parseDouble(s);
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a number");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("You entered : " + length1);
```

If the user gave a valid numerical input, then the number is able to be parsed.  Otherwise, a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown, an you can prompt the user to enter a number.  The code will repeat because of the `while` loop until the user puts in a valid number.

Comment: Please enter the length in centimeters : 9
You entered : 9.0

Value: 
java.lang.NullPointerExceptionYou entered:  0.0: Please enter a number                                                                           Just wondering if I can not have it to display that last bit? Thanks though :)

Comment: @user2863681 I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Basically when I run the program and enter a valid number, it displays: Please enter the length in centimeters : 9
You entered : 9.0
                                                                                    
"""""""Value: 
java.lang.NullPointerExceptionYou entered:  0.0: Please enter a number""""""    any way of having it to not display this last bit in the console message thing which i've put in quotation marks?

Comment: @user2863681 I tested the code, and I am not able to reproduce that error.

Comment: Ah ok, no worries, thats great anyways, appreciate the help :)